# How to manipulate the selected text from textarea by JS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a small snippet about grabbing selected text and it works well.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39gb30cv/)
HTML

```
<textarea id="text">
    This is just a test!
</textarea>
<button>go</button>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $("button").on("click", function(){
        getWords();
    });
});

function getWords(){   
    var textComponent = document.getElementById('text');
    var selectedText;
    // IE version
    if (document.selection != undefined)
    {
        textComponent.focus();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        selectedText = sel.text;
    }
    // Mozilla version
    else if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined)
    {
        var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
        var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
        selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos)
    }
    //alert(selectedText);
    //whats next?
    //selectedText = "<p>"+selectedText+"</p>";
    //alert(selectedText);
}
```

I can grab the text but how can I style or manipulate the text? For instance, the original text is

```
This is just a test!
```

I want to wrap a p tag with highlighted "a test!".

```
This is just
<p>a test!</p>
```

I can do

```
selectedText = "<p>"+selectedText+"</p>"
```

But what's next? How to place it into the textarea and remain other texts?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Form fields (like textareas) only display plain text (ie. it will not render HTML codes in it).

Comment: If you just wish to add additional text into a textarea, you can do this: $('#myTextarea').val($('#myTextarea').val() + 'some additional text'). Additionally, you can convert a string into a jQuery element by wrapping it with a selector: $("<p>"+selectedText+"</p>").appendTo("#myDiv");

Comment: that's not what I want, sry

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
var precedingText = textComponent.value.substr(0, startPos - 1);
var followingText = textComponent.value.substr(endPos + 1);
textComponent.innerHTML = precedingText 
    + "<p>" + selectedText + "</p>" 
    + followingText;
```

But for a browser-agnostic solution you really ought to look into using jQuery. It's a lot of fun.

Answer (score 0):

First, does p tag highlight text ? If it does, so...

There is many way to answer :

1. DOM object

> var wrapper = document.createElement( "p" );
>
> wrapper.appendChild( textComponent );
>
> alert( wrapper.outerHTML );

2. With Jquery

> var wrapper = $( textComponent ).wrap("< p>")[ 0 ];
>
> alert( wrapper.outerHTML );

3. With simple JS

> textComponent.innerHTML = "< p>" + textComponent.innerHTML + "< p>";
>
> alert( textComponent.outerHTML );

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as it is:

```
$(function () {
    $("button").on("click", function () {
        var el = document.getElementById("text");
        replaceSelectedText(el);
    });
});

function getInputSelection(el) {
    var start = 0,
        end = 0,
        normalizedValue, range,
        textInputRange, len, endRange;

    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
        start = el.selectionStart;
        end = el.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        range = document.selection.createRange();

        if (range && range.parentElement() == el) {
            len = el.value.length;
            normalizedValue = el.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");

            textInputRange = el.createTextRange();
            textInputRange.moveToBookmark(range.getBookmark());

            // Check if the start and end of the selection are at the very end
            // of the input, since moveStart/moveEnd doesn't return what we want
            // in those cases
            endRange = el.createTextRange();
            endRange.collapse(false);

            if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("StartToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
                start = end = len;
            } else {
                start = -textInputRange.moveStart("character", -len);
                start += normalizedValue.slice(0, start).split("\n").length - 1;

                if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("EndToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
                    end = len;
                } else {
                    end = -textInputRange.moveEnd("character", -len);
                    end += normalizedValue.slice(0, end).split("\n").length - 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    };
}

function replaceSelectedText(el) {
    var sel = getInputSelection(el),
        val = el.value;
    text = '<p>'+val.slice(sel.start,sel.end)+'</p>';
    el.value = val.slice(0, sel.start) + text + val.slice(sel.end);
}
```